# Binding data in gridview using inner join

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a mysql database and I am trying to populate the gridview with the inner join query but I can't work it out. Here is my code.

```
    Sub loadingaccess4()
    Dim adapter As New OdbcDataAdapter("Select customer.CustomerName,   customer.CustomerID from customer INNER JOIN transaction on customer.CustomerID=transaction.CustomerID", dbconn)
    Dim dataset As New DataSet

    dataset.Clear()
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "")
    Me.GridView4.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Me.GridView4.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Can you help me?

Sorry guys, okay I am going to clarify. The gridview shows nothing. Is my code wrong or something?

Comment: What is the error? What does "can't work it out" mean? At first glance `adapter.Fill(dataset, "")` doesn't seem right, cause you are saying adapter to use table named "", which does not exist.

Comment: I mean I can't seem to put the data in the gridview what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's going wrong with populating the gridview? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use

```
    Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection string here")
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim SQLReader As SqlDataReader

    conn2.Open()

    command = New SqlCommand("Select customer.CustomerName,   customer.CustomerID from customer   INNER JOIN transaction on customer.CustomerID=transaction.CustomerID", conn2)

    SQLReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    GridView4.DataSource = SQLReader 
    GridView4.DataBind()
```

Then bind them to the gridview using this

```
<asp:Label ID="lable1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim dt as new DataTable();
command.CommandType = CommandType.CommandText
command.CommandText = "Select customer.CustomerName,   customer.CustomerID from customer   INNER JOIN transaction on customer.CustomerID=transaction.CustomerID"
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
Me.GridView4.DataSource = dt
Me.GridView4.DataBind()
```